# one-to-one not working in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using one-to-one assocation but it does not work. May be it's because of the column name are not same in table.

i have 2 tables. 1) USER_DC and 2)USER

In USER, the primary key is - "ID"

In USER_DC, there is a fereign key, but the name is : "USER_ID"

Need help, how can I define one-to-one relationship?

### `In User.hbm.xml`

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.test.User" table="USER">
 <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long" length="10">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">USER_SEQ</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
:
:
```

### `In userDC.hbm.xml`

```
:
:
<one-to-one name="user" class="com.test.User"></one-to-one>
<one-to-one name="dc" class="com.test.DC"></one-to-one>
```

It does not work

Comment: actually I have many one-to-one association in userDC. 

1) for User
2) for DC

But the question is, for user, how it can know for which reference key it should use?

For example, when I use
<one-to-one name="user" class="com.test.User"></one-to-one>

How hibernate can know where user is for user_id or dc_id?

Comment: Did you checked out [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html). It seems it won't be a problem.

Comment: Yes I visited many sites including the dzone. But they didn't help.

Comment: Step by step tutorial.. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/  ....or post your problem briefly

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing me the links. However I already visited all those links and googled. 

They all do have only one one-to-one associations and that too the same columns across both the tables.

But mine is different.

Comment: Just mention the error what your getting..

Comment: there is no error. However when I use the query:

select udc.dc from UserDC udc where udc.user.id = :usrId order by udc.dc.id

so it joins the DC table in the query it produced thru hibernate, but not the user table. Any error in the query?

Comment: Please complete the question with your last remark.

Comment: If you notice the query:

"select distributi1_* ............
from USER_DC userdistri0_ 
inner join DC distributi1_
on userdistri0_.ID=distributi1_.DC_NUMBER
where userdistri0_.ID=322
order by userdistri0_.ID",

it joins DC table instead the User table.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the one-to-one mapping is that the primary key is propagated from the entity with the one-to-one to the target entity - so in your case it wants to propagate the id from UserDC to User.  This is not how you've defined your database tables.

I think the way you want to map it instead is to use a many-to-one with a unique constraint.

In UserDC.hbm.xml, you'd have the following:

```
<many-to-one name="user" class="com.test.User" column="USER_ID" unique="true"/>
```

Does your database enforce the one-to-one constraint that multiple UserDC rows cannot have the same value for UserDC.USER_ID?  Otherwise, you don't have a one-to-one, but a many-to-one.

Hope this helps.

Sarah